# Preventing files from being renamed when camera uploads to Dropbox is enabled

Tags: macos, backup, dropbox

Is there any way to prevent files from being renamed when camera uploads to Dropbox is enabled in Mac OS X?

[image]

By default all imported image files are renamed into their timestamps:

[image]

I think to keep the original filenames:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current version of Dropbox client you can't.
If you want your photos to be uploaded to Dropbox and not renamed you have to rely on different solution than Dropbox.app

You might [go to their forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions) though and request this to be available.